# Can not select sub options when there are more than one rows in a table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table, which has 2 columns. First column is maindrop down list of options and second column is a corresponding sub dropdown list of options for the main drop down.

Everything works fine for single row, but as soon as I have multiple rows, nothing is selected from subdrop down menu.

Below is the simple html and JavaScript to reproduce this problem. If you uncomment the second row, you will see the problem. Hope someone can help me in this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

</head>
<body>

<script language="JavaScript">
    function SubCat(cn, scn, scnm)

    {
        this.CatNum = cn;
        this.SubcatNum = scn;
        this.SubcatName = scnm;
    }
    var subcatInfo = new Array(

    new SubCat('26', '1', 'MainOpt1_SubOpt1'),

    new SubCat('26', '2', 'MainOpt1_SubOpt2'),

    new SubCat('27', '3', 'MainOpt2_SubOpt1'),

    new SubCat('27', '4', 'MainOpt2_SubOpt2')

    );
    function doCategory(sel) {

        var ix;
        var subcat = sel.form.repairSubcategoryCode;



        // regardless of what else we do, we wipe out all the 
        // options in the subcategory dropdown by
        // going backwards, removing selected options 
        for (ix = subcat.options.length - 1; ix >= 0; --ix) {
            subcat.options[ix] = null;
        }
        // now, did the user select a category? 
        if (sel.selectedIndex == 0) {
            // no...so give user the "no subcats" msg 
            subcat.options[0] = new Option("-- no subcategories yet --", "0");
            return; // and we are done 
        }
        // yes, so get the appropriate subcategories: 
        subcat.options[0] = new Option("-- choose a subcategory below --", "0");

        // what category number was selected?
        var catnum = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
        var cursc = 0;
        for (ix = 0; ix < subcatInfo.length; ++ix) {
            // looking for all subcat's with the requested category number
            var subcatObj = subcatInfo[ix];
            if (subcatObj.CatNum == catnum) {
                subcat.options[++cursc] = new Option(subcatObj.SubcatName,
                        subcatObj.SubcatNum);
            }
        }
    }
</script language="JavaScript">
<form name="priceOpinionForm" method="post" action="/brokerPriceOpinion.do">
    <table  id="repirImprTab">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="repairTypeCode" onchange="doCategory(this)">
                    <option value="-1">Select Repair Type</option>
                    <option value="26">MainOpt1</option>
                    <option value="27">MainOpt2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="repairSubcategoryCode" >
                    <OPTION Value="-1">-- now subcategories yet --</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- 
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="repairTypeCode" onchange="doCategory(this)">
                    <option value="-1">Select Repair Type</option>
                    <option value="25">Septic Maintenance</option>
                    <option value="26">Bathroom Items</option>
                    <option value="27">Cabinets &amp; Shelves</option>
                    <option value="28">Counter Tops</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="repairSubcategoryCode">
                    <OPTION Value="-1">-- now subcategories yet --</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
         -->
    </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For starters, `</script language="JavaScript">` is wrong.

Comment: Yes @DreamEater, however, that isn't the issue at all and is not breaking the code.

Answer (score 0):

Every named field in an HTML form may only have one value at a time. In your case, there would be multiple selects named "repairTypeCode" and "repairSubcategoryCode", which leads to all fields with the same name being set to the same value if any one of them is changed.

Fix: Append an numerical index to the names (e.g. "repairTypeCode1", "repairTypeCode2", ...) or convert them into array (e.g. "repairTypeCode[]").

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. Let me  try these. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

AS Kurrija mentioned, you cannot have two elements named the same.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2S3u/) with an added variable for the `doCategory` method which allows the code to decide which sub category dropdown to populate. I've changed the `name` attribute to `id` as well to provide better readability.